# facebook like/send button homepage domain not getting metadata

Tags: facebook, indexing, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph, facebook-social-plugins

I added the like/send button on my homepage, http://www.website.com, for example.
But, when people like it or send it, it doesnt get the metadata, only when I post with the index page, like this: http://www.website.com/index.html

How can I resolve this? I want the link to be shared by people to be the .com one, but with the metadata from the index!

Answer (score 0):

You can force facebook to update meta information by running the url in the Linter

see https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

The linter will scrape the page for meta tags, update facebook and show any errors related to the tags on the page.